# QEMU crashes while method execution

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, qemu

I wrote really simple a C kernel and a bootloader. I'm loading the kernel in the QEMU like this:

```
qemu-system-i386 kernel.image
```

When I load the kernel and switch from real mode to protected mode (that step success completed) and `main` method start execute other method like this 
    `void foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {return;}`. But it execution leads to crash QEMU. However if I rewrite `foo` method for `void foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) {return;}` - everything will be ok. Here is the error information:
    (qemu) qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xf4000010

```
EAX=ffffffff EBX=00001000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=ae00008f ESP=00008fcd
EIP=f4000010 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c75 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00008fc5 CCO=INCL    
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000       XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

My bootloader.S

```
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]
    mov bp, 0x8000 
    mov sp, bp     
    mov bx, bootstring
    call print          

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
    mov dh, 3h           
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    call load_kernel
    call enable_A20
    call init_protected
loop:
    jmp loop

bootstring:   db "Loading...", 0
BOOT_DRIVE:   db 0

print:
    mov ah, 0xE 
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, 0    
    jz print_done
    int 0x10     
    inc bx       
    jmp print    
print_done:
    ret

load_kernel:
    push dx        
    mov ah, 0x02   
    mov al, dh     
    mov ch, 0      
    mov cl, 2      
    mov dh, 0      
    int 0x13       
    jc load_error  
    pop dx         
    cmp al, dh     

    jne load_error  
    ret

load_error:
    mov bx, load_err_msg
    call print
    jmp $

enable_A20:
    cli

    call a20wait
    mov al, 0xAD
    out 0x64, al

    call a20wait
    mov al, 0xD0
    out 0x64, al

    call a20wait2
    in al, 0x60
    push eax

    call a20wait
    mov al, 0xD1
    out 0x64, al

    call a20wait
    pop eax
    or al, 2
    out 0x60, al

    call a20wait
    mov al, 0xAE
    out 0x64, al

    call a20wait
    sti
    ret

a20wait:
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 2
    jnz a20wait
    ret

a20wait2:
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 1
    jz a20wait2
    ret

load_err_msg: db "Cannot load from disk", 0

gdt:                
gdt_null: 
    dd 0  
    dd 0  
gdt_cs:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0     
    db 0     
    db 10011010b

    db 11001111b
    db 0        
gdt_ds:
    dw 0xffff   
    dw 0        
    db 0        
    db 10010010b

    db 11001111b
    db 0        
gdt_end:        

gdt_desc:
    dw gdt_end - gdt - 1
    dd gdt

CODE_SEG equ gdt_cs - gdt
DATA_SEG equ gdt_ds - gdt

[bits 16]
init_protected:
    cli
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x9000      
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xFFFF
    lgdt [gdt_desc]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:start_protected

[bits 32]

start_protected:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov esp, 0x9000   
    call KERNEL_OFFSET

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0  
dw 0xAA55
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: are you really expecting us to debug your kernel without giving us your kernel? Obviously, you breach protection *somehow*, but how is really impossible to tell.

Comment: Really? Are you serious? Give us the code to the kernel.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, I editet post ;)

Comment: I don't know about your question, but I find the way you calculate the segment selectors a bit strange: `DATA_SEG equ gdt_ds - gdt`. It's just an index. No TI and RPL fields. And the index shouldn't be byte-based; it should be 0 for the first segment descriptor, 1 for the second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms suggest that your stack memory is not set up correctly -- it looks like things go wrong when there are enough arguments to the function that some of them have to go on the stack rather than all being in registers. The message from QEMU is telling you that your guest tried to execute from a physical address with no RAM in it. You should be able to debug what exactly has gone wrong using the debug logging options (-d in_asm,exec,cpu,int -D qemu.log) to see what the CPU actually did to get to a point where it tried to execute from an invalid address.

Note that although the QEMU error message looks a bit like "QEMU crashed" it always indicates a guest OS bug.